# Combine orderByPriority with equalTo

Tags: firebase

I have a dataset like this:

```
[
  {
    "projectId": "fdsFDSFaSdA",
    "teamId": "ASDasdASDsada"
    ...
  },
  {
    "projectId": "DSF432afdsf",
    "teamId": "fdsASfsdasdd"
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

I nead to select objects from this list sometimes by projectId, sometimes by teamId.

I know that this is possible like so:

```
ref.orderByChild('key').equalTo(value)
```

But the problem is that I need to order by `priority`.

I see that `equalTo()` takes two parameters:

```
equalTo(value, [key])
```

I tried like so but it doesn't work:

```
ref.orderByPriority().equalTo(value, 'key')
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Firebase queries can only order/filter on a single value. Your last example is trying to order on two values. This will not work.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen So then how does this actually work? The docs say you can only use the optional key in `equalTo` if ordering by priority, but you can't order by priority. I'm yet to find a working example of the key with `equalTo`.

Comment: BTW @John did you get a chance to get this working?