# Firebase orderByPriority used with equalTo strange behavior

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to use the second argument of `equalTo(value, key)` when using `orderByPriority()`, as [documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ThenableReference?hl=da#equalTo).

The problem is that results are inconsistent when using that second `key` argument.

---

**Example dataset**

```
items
  key1
  key2
  key3
  key4
```

*All items have the same priority: 10 (this is just for the example, in my app there are other items with other priorities)*

---

When issuing the following Firebase query to get the first two items with that priority:

```
dbRef.child('items').orderByPriority().equalTo(10).limitToFirst(2)
```

I get the following - expected - results :

```
{ "key1": ..., "key2": ... }
```

---

Then I try to get the results after the `key2` item, as explained in the docs:

```
dbRef.child('items').orderByPriority().equalTo(10, 'key2').limitToFirst(2)
```

Result is pretty strange, with always only one item, the one with the provided key:

```
{ "key2": ... }
```

What i was expecting is two results *starting at* or *after* the key provided, so

```
{ "key2": ..., "key3": ... }
```

Or

```
{ "key3": ..., "key4": ... }
```

---

**Question**

How should I use the `equalTo()` filter with its second argument?

---

*It seem this question was [already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140189/combine-orderbypriority-with-equalto), but it did not get any answers...*

Answer (score 1):

The equalTo() filter will only get items exactly matching the key specified. If you'd like to start at 'key2' and get multiple after that, use the startAt() filter. You cannot use multiple orderBy statements in the same query, though, so you may need to reformat your code. I would recommend that you save items by desired priority. Then you can query that group of items using the startAt() filter. Heres a dataset:

```
items10
  key1
  key2
items9
  key1
  key2
```

In the startAt() filter, you specify the starting key, and then it will query for any key with the same or greater value. Here's a link to the docs for this functionality: [startAt()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/startat.html).

Using this method, limitToFirst(2) should give you key2 and key3. Here's a code example, using priority 10.

```
    dbRef.child('items10').orderByKey().startAt('key2').limitToFirst(2)
```

Note: you may also need to just grab an element, without knowing its priority. For this, create another key called items that just contains all keys (you would not use this for queries).

Comment: That does not work: `Error: Query.orderByKey: You can't combine multiple orderBy calls`. Also, where did you see that the `equalTo()` filter will only get the item matching the key? The docs say: `The child key to start at, among the children with the previously specified priority.`

Comment: And to answer your question, you are only allowed to filter based on one value. That is just the nature of Firebase queries

Comment: When using `startAt()`, the second argument is used to start at a specified key when multiple values are the same, as per the docs - *and it works*. The `equalTo()` documents are about the same, but the actual behaviour is different, why? That's my question.